# php mysql, queries get locked and never returned

Tags: php, mysql

[image: locked and never released]

My system creates a lot of transactions as it has many users and a lot of data which is checked on a daily basis and renewed.

Somehow at a certain moment (i am not sure if it is the backup which did it) there is a LOCKED on queries. And Somehow they are never returned. Is this the deadlock?
The database is not returning anything to the code either, so I can't check if it's locked or not. Also, this causes other queries to be stopped and pile up and my server runs out of connections...

any idea's on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be caused by several issues. Most popular is MyISAM table lock. Just run this quesry: `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Table%';`. Post it here. If `Table_locks_waited` is big (e.g. more than 0.5% of `Table_locks_immediate`) and you are using MyISAM switch to InnoDB table engine.

If your database is not very big, changing engine is pretty fast and transparent.

Note, that all your locked queries are "write" queries. That's because MyISAM has long running selects that lock tables. Moreover, selects can cause some kind of deadlock. Quotation from [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html):

> MySQL grants table write locks as follows:
>
> 1. If there are **no locks on the table**, put a write lock on it.
> 2. Otherwise, put the lock request in the write lock queue.
>
> MySQL grants table read locks as follows:
>
> 1. If there are no write locks on the table, put a read lock on it.
> 2. Otherwise, put the lock request in the read lock queue.

Don't forget to tune innodb_* params!

If you don't want to switch to InnoDB (why?!), you can tune [concurrent_insert parameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert) (try "2") in your my.cnf.

Btw, I see a lot of sleeping connections. Do you have persistent connections? If "yes", do you close them properly?